# Copy pasting spreadsheet/excel data into Ruby console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, spreadsheet

I often have to import excel data into my production ruby console, and I'm having a hard time figuring the best, fast way to do that.

Currently, I'm copying my Google spreadhseet range into [Mr Data Converter](https://shancarter.github.io/mr-data-converter/), exporting as JSON, and I have to rewrite the JSON so it looks like a Ruby Hash, so I can copy-paste the final output into my ruby console and assign it to a variable.

Anyone has a faster way ? I also tried to just use a ruby string `<<-RAW`, copy paste my JSON data and try to `JSON.parse(raw)` but it seems to fail at times...

Sample of data I copy paste into Mr Data Converter (h for header, v for value)

```
h1  h2  h3  h4
v11 V12 V13 v14
v21 V22 v23 v24
```

Sample Data I get from Conversion

```
[{"h1":"v11","h2":"v12","h3":"v13","h4":"v14"},
 {"h1":"v21","h2":"v22","h3":"v23","h4":"v24"},
]
```

I may have special characters like `"` or `:`, which is the cause for many failures.

Do you have a fast way to copy-paste code from excel into a ruby console ?

Comment: "Mr Data Converter" has a "Ruby" output option.

Comment: Hit me please 

Comment: Oh actually it seems I still have export problems (even with Ruby) with my strings... it would seem one of the cells is exported without surrounding quotes which causes a parsing problem `"h1"=>String not surrounded by quotes,"h2é=> ...`

Comment: Can you be more specific? Maybe an actual Google spreadsheet would help.